# Bar charts & Combination charts in 3D format

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, charts, chartjs

please I have a question:
Is it possible to have a Bar charts and also a Combination charts but in 3D format?

I  know that we have the models that salesforce offers but they are not 3D, so do i have to develop them with LWC? If yes do you have a documentation to follow or an example somewhere , because i searched but i did not find what i want .

Comment: its important to include your researched resources, otherwise, others might provide you the same docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Yes, you have to develop them.

here is a SF documented example on using a 3rd party lib for data visualization:
[3rd party libraries in lwc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_third_party_library)

and here is a random example, using that library, how to do a 3d chart

[3D bar chart](http://bl.ocks.org/austinhyde/02a038074dbd9a7b1eb3)

Comment: thank you for your time and for your help , i marked your answer